# NodeJS - Paths break after deployment

Tags: node.js, deployment, path, require, supervisord

I deploy my NodeJS Projects with **supervisord**. Strangely most of the paths, which are paths

- inside the served **index.html**: links to static files (stylesheets and js files)
- inside **javascript files**, require statements to other files(e.g.: require('./scripts/'))

I believe the reason for that to be the command `node "path/to/my/application/app"` since it runs the application from a different directory.

How can i avoid changing the paths whenever i push a new version of my application to production?
Can you recommend any tools to solve this problem? Is there a clean way of setting the paths so that the application works so i can run it from anywhere(my local machine/my webspace)?

Comment: Any update on this?

Answer (score 0):

Use a relative path. For example if index.html is in a directory as same as a .js file referring it u can use ('./index.html'). If it were in a parent directory u could use (../index.html)